# Google Cloud Firestore REST API createDocument auto genarates ID and add as field value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Google Cloud Firestore with Rest API.
I want to create a Document with auto generated uniq id.
And use that uniq id as field value in that document like **ticketNo** in that document.
Same as shown in figure.

[image: Document name and field value as same]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: The SDKs just generate the ID in the client app, not on the backend.  The IDs don't have any meaning - they are truly random.  You can simply do the same with a UUID library or similar to generate an ID.  You can combine IDs from various sources and it won't matter at all - they are all still unique even if they lack uniformity of structure.

Comment: Autogenerated Firebase ID's are lexicographic and unique and do provide ordering. The title of your question indicates you are familiar with createDocument and auto generated ID's so... what's the question? Generally speaking, storing a document ID within the same document that has that ID is just duplicate data. In other words if you know a documentID you want, you don't need to query for it, just read that document directly.

Comment: @Jay It can help to have the ID in a document in order for it to be automatically mapped into a data structure without having to write extra code to deal with non-field values like the doc ID.  Also, IDs in fields can make it possible to perform a collection group query that wants to find all documents with an ID (collection group queries can't consider the normal doc ID as a filter).

Comment: Ah. yes, Thanks  @DougStevenson. The use case wasn't really clear but thanks for clarifying that point - definitely needed over collection group queries.

Comment: Yes, @DougStevenson you are right. That's reason for which I asked this question. I know I can do this with two API call. But now I am generating uniq ID and use that as document id and also used as field value.

Answer (score 1):

If you need REST API method, check out this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument?authuser=0&hl=en (you also can test the function with 'Try out' button)

documented is expected in query, but according to description it's optional:

> Optional. If not specified, an ID will be assigned by the service.

Comment: Thanks. And I know thats key is option and it assign by service a uniq key but I want to know that key for adding in field value.

Comment: this key will be returned to you in response. If you need to duplicate the key as the value in document without second call, you can use the write cloud function that will   add field once new document created